# PHP Email form sending blank messages

Tags: php, html, email

I added a clean() function to my contact me form to strip special chars, and for some reason it's just sending blank messages, no subject, nothing. If I remove the function from the strings then it works.

Here's part of the form:

```
function clean($string) {
preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/', '', strip_tags(html_entity_decode($string)));
}

if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))
  {//if "email" is filled out, proceed

  //check if the email address is invalid
  $mailcheck = spamcheck($_REQUEST['email']);
  if ($mailcheck==FALSE)
    {
    echo "Invalid input. Please <a href='http://pattersoncode.ca/index.php?a=help'>try again</a>";
    }
  else
    {//send email
    $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
    $product = clean($_REQUEST['product']);
    $message = clean($_REQUEST['message']);
    mail("support@pattersoncode.ca", "Subject: $product",
    $message, "From: $email" );
    echo "I'll be in contact shortly, thanks! :)";
    }
```

Comment: You are not returning any value from your function

Answer (score 2):

You need to **return** a value from your function.

```
function clean($string) {
return preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/', '', strip_tags(html_entity_decode($string)));
}
```